# Sql Query Assistance - Removing Duplicates from CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need assistance in writing a query that looks to see if a customer has a specific product.

As you will see from the first image, ID 4169137 has returned 2 rows. I really want to consolidate results into a signal row.  Meaning, if there is a YES in either row, return YES.  If they are both NO, return NO.

[image]

Here is how I want the output to look like.

[image]

Here is the query that I have been working with.

```
SELECT  distinct A.ID as 'ID'
        ,(CASE WHEN b.isProductA = 1    THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'A'
        ,(CASE WHEN b.isProductB = 1    THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'B'
        ,(CASE WHEN b.isProductC = 1    THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'C'        
        ,(CASE WHEN b.isProductD = 1    THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'D'    
        ,(CASE WHEN b.isProductE = 1    THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'E'
        ,(CASE WHEN b.isProductF = 1    THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'F'                         
FROM  [source].[Opportunity] A 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  distinct ProductFamilyName, isProductA, isProductB, isProductC, isProductD, isProductE, isProductF
            FROM [reference].[ProductFamilyMapping] B
        ) b ON a.ProductFamily = b.ProductFamilyName
```

Comment: Can you do this numerically by converting no to 0 and yes to 1 and checking the sum of each column is greater than 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for case, just use aggregate function directly:

```
SELECT ID, 
  MAX(A) AS A,
  MAX(B) AS B,
  MAX(C) AS C,
  MAX(D) AS D,
  MAX(E) AS E,
  MAX(F) AS F
FROM ...
GROUP BY ID;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82942/1)**:

```
|      ID |  A |  B |   C |   D |   E |   F |
|---------|----|----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 4169137 | no | no | yes | yes | yes | yes |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Z.ID as 'ID',
(CASE WHEN Z.isProductA > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'A',
(CASE WHEN Z.isProductB > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'B',
(CASE WHEN Z.isProductC > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'C',        
(CASE WHEN Z.isProductD > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'D',    
(CASE WHEN Z.isProductE > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'E',
(CASE WHEN Z.isProductF > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as 'F'
FROM
(
    SELECT A.ID, 
    SUM(b.isProductA) as total_A,
    SUM(b.isProductB) as total_B,
    SUM(b.isProductC) as total_C,
    SUM(b.isProductD) as total_D,
    SUM(b.isProductE) as total_E,
    SUM(b.isProductF) as total_F
    FROM  [source].[Opportunity] A 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  distinct ProductFamilyName, isProductA, isProductB, isProductC, isProductD, isProductE, isProductF
        FROM [reference].[ProductFamilyMapping] B
    ) b ON a.ProductFamily = b.ProductFamilyName
    GROUP BY A.ID
) Z;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Vashi. I keep getting the following error "Incorrect syntax near 'Z'."